# create a route with URL of other website laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function redirectToForm()
{
    $redirect = url('/form_callback') . '/redirect_to_url=' . 
    request('redirect_to_url');
}
```

In laravel I want to create a route with URL of other website. Above `request('redirect_to_url')` contains 
URL of other site e.g. '`http://localhost.studentform.com/`'.
So the URL which generates is:

```
http://localhost.studentInformation.com/form_callback/redirect_to_url=http://localhost.studentform.com/
```

So I need to create a route for the same , in laravel 5.3
currently I am following:

```
Route::get('/form_callback/{redirectTo}', ['as' => 'student.callback.to', 'uses' => 'StudentController@functionCallback']);
```

But it says route not found

Comment: The route you created expects your URL to be in the form of `/form_callback/http://localhost..`, which yours isn't, so no route found.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Change it to:

```
Route::get('/form_callback/redirect_to_url={redirectTo}', ....
```

And get the data in a controller method:

```
public function functionCallback($redirectTo)
{
    dd($redirectTo);
```

**2.** Or change it to:

```
Route::get('form_callback', ....
```

Url to:

`http://localhost.studentInformation.com/form_callback?redirect_to_url=http://localhost.studentform.com/`

And get the data in a controller with:

```
$url = request('redirect_to_url')
```